# Docker compose unsupported config option

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to setup a docker to run mysql Mosquitto and node red but keep getting the unsupported config option errors..

```
Services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - “6603:3306”
    Environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: “abcd1234”
    volumes:
      - mysql-data

  node-red:
    image: nodered/node-red:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: nodered
    environment:
      -TZ=Europe/London
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - “1880:1880”
    links:
      - mysql:mysql
      - mosquitto:mosquitto
    volumes:
      - node-red-data

  mosquitto:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto
    hostname: mosquitto
    container_name: mosquitto
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "1883:1883"

volumes:
  mysql-data:
  node-red-data:
```

Any thoughts on why im getting these errors?

```
Unsupported config option for Services: 'mosquitto'
Unsupported config option for volumes: 'mysql-data'
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a version tag at the top of your docker-compose file. Also shouldn't `Services` be all lowercase?

Comment: Please make sure your file respect the standard provided in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/)